# How do I split the output from mysqldump into smaller files?

Tags: mysql, migration

I need to move entire tables from one MySQL database to another. I don't have full access to the second one, only phpMyAdmin access. I can only upload (compressed) sql files smaller than 2MB. But the compressed output from a mysqldump of the first database's tables is larger than 10MB.

Is there a way to split the output from mysqldump into smaller files? I cannot use split(1) since I cannot cat(1) the files back on the remote server.

Or is there another solution I have missed?

**Edit**

The --extended-insert=FALSE option to mysqldump suggested by the first poster yields a .sql file that can then be split into importable files, provided that split(1) is called with a suitable --lines option. By trial and error I found that bzip2 compresses the .sql files by a factor of 20, so I needed to figure out how many lines of sql code correspond roughly to 40MB.

Comment: look at this Q in case you search how to [split a large postgresql dump into smaller files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/351546/split-a-large-postgresql-dump-into-smaller-files)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

First dump the schema (it surely fits in 2Mb, no?)

```
mysqldump -d --all-databases
```

and restore it.

Afterwards dump only the data in separate insert statements, so you can split the files and restore them without having to concatenate them on the remote server

```
mysqldump --all-databases --extended-insert=FALSE --no-create-info=TRUE
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to enable an INSERT statement for each row inserted, rather than one massive statement with many tuples or each row using VALUES. The `--extended-insert=FALSE` flag was what I needed. thanks!

Comment: Create table: `mysqldump mydatabase mytable -d > mytable-create.sql`

The data: 
`mysqldump mydatabase mytable --extended-insert=FALSE --no-create-info=TRUE > mytable-data.sql`

Then split it up into a series of files of whatever length: 

`split mytable-data.sql -l10000`

Now you can import first the create SQL. Then each of the tables of 10,000 length. By default files will be named xaa, xab, xac...). Important them by 

`mysql mydatabase < xaa` etc etc.

Comment: Setting `--extended-insert=FALSE` severely crippled the import times of large data tables for me. I don't see how that helps, though. Even when set to `TRUE`, `INSERT` statements are all on a single line so you can safely split the dump file by n lines and the only thing you are going to lose is the lock when switching to import more data to the same table from the next file (which you can re-establish by simply `cat`ing it).

Answer (score 49):

This bash script splits a dumpfile of one database into separate files for each table and names with [csplit](http://linux.die.net/man/1/csplit) and names them accordingly:

```
#!/bin/bash

####
# Split MySQL dump SQL file into one file per table
# based on https://gist.github.com/jasny/1608062
####

#adjust this to your case:
START="/-- Table structure for table/"
# or 
#START="/DROP TABLE IF EXISTS/"


if [ $# -lt 1 ] || [[ $1 == "--help" ]] || [[ $1 == "-h" ]] ; then
        echo "USAGE: extract all tables:"
        echo " $0 DUMP_FILE"
        echo "extract one table:"
        echo " $0 DUMP_FILE [TABLE]"
        exit
fi

if [ $# -ge 2 ] ; then
        #extract one table $2
        csplit -s -ftable $1 "/-- Table structure for table/" "%-- Table structure for table \`$2\`%" "/-- Table structure for table/" "%40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE%1"
else
        #extract all tables
        csplit -s -ftable $1 "$START" {*}
fi
 
[ $? -eq 0 ] || exit
 
mv table00 head
 
FILE=`ls -1 table* | tail -n 1`
if [ $# -ge 2 ] ; then
        # cut off all other tables
        mv $FILE foot
else
        # cut off the end of each file
        csplit -b '%d' -s -f$FILE $FILE "/40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE/" {*}
        mv ${FILE}1 foot
fi
 
for FILE in `ls -1 table*`; do
        NAME=`head -n1 $FILE | cut -d$'\x60' -f2`
        cat head $FILE foot > "$NAME.sql"
done
 
rm head foot table*
```

based on https://gist.github.com/jasny/1608062
and https://stackoverflow.com/a/16840625/1069083

Comment: Need to note that csplit on the Mac does not work with this script because it doesn't support the {*} syntax. Need to run it in Linux.

Comment: Same on FreeBSD. But you can install there the sysutils/coreutils port or package to get GNU utilities and use gcsplit instead.

Comment: Oh man, I cannot than you enough for this script. I had a 3TB mysqlDump that failed twice and now I'm able to import it table by table and resume where I left if it fails. Lots of love sent your way.

Comment: Da best. mysqldump does not work with --tab option when database is in other server than localhost. So you can dump all database, redirect the output to one file and then split tables with that script! But I'm searching for a way to do as --tab option: split structure as sql file and data as txt tab-separated data. Any magic script for that, or would I create another split and conversion script?

Answer (score 18):

There is this excellent [mysqldumpsplitter](https://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/mydumpsplitter-extract-tables-from-mysql-dump-shell-script) script which comes with tons of option for when it comes to extracting-from-mysqldump.

I would copy the recipe here to choose your case from:

> 1. Extract single database from mysqldump:
>
> `sh mysqldumpsplitter.sh --source filename --extract DB --match_str database-name`
>
> Above command will create sql for specified database from specified
> "filename" sql file and store it in compressed format to
> database-name.sql.gz.
>
> 2. Extract single table from mysqldump:
>
> `sh mysqldumpsplitter.sh --source filename --extract TABLE --match_str table-name`
>
> Above command will create sql for specified table from specified
> "filename" mysqldump file and store it in compressed format to
> database-name.sql.gz.
>
> 3. Extract tables matching regular expression from mysqldump:
>
> `sh mysqldumpsplitter.sh --source filename --extract REGEXP --match_str regular-expression`
>
> Above command will create sqls for tables matching specified regular
> expression from specified "filename" mysqldump file and store it in
> compressed format to individual table-name.sql.gz.
>
> 4. Extract all databases from mysqldump:
>
> `sh mysqldumpsplitter.sh --source filename --extract ALLDBS`
>
> Above command will extract all databases from specified "filename"
> mysqldump file and store it in compressed format to individual
> database-name.sql.gz.
>
> 5. Extract all table from mysqldump:
>
> `sh mysqldumpsplitter.sh --source filename --extract ALLTABLES`
>
> Above command will extract all tables from specified "filename"
> mysqldump file and store it in compressed format to individual
> table-name.sql.gz.
>
> 6. Extract list of tables from mysqldump:
>
> `sh mysqldumpsplitter.sh --source filename --extract REGEXP --match_str '(table1|table2|table3)'`
>
> Above command will extract tables from the specified "filename"
> mysqldump file and store them in compressed format to individual
> table-name.sql.gz.
>
> 7. Extract a database from compressed mysqldump:
>
> `sh mysqldumpsplitter.sh --source filename.sql.gz --extract DB --match_str 'dbname' --decompression gzip`
>
> Above command will decompress filename.sql.gz using gzip, extract
> database named "dbname" from "filename.sql.gz" & store it as
> out/dbname.sql.gz
>
> 8. Extract a database from compressed mysqldump in an uncompressed
>    format:
>
> `sh mysqldumpsplitter.sh --source filename.sql.gz --extract DB --match_str 'dbname' --decompression gzip --compression none`
>
> Above command will decompress filename.sql.gz using gzip and extract
> database named "dbname" from "filename.sql.gz" & store it as plain sql
> out/dbname.sql
>
> 9. Extract alltables from mysqldump in different folder:
>
> `sh mysqldumpsplitter.sh --source filename --extract ALLTABLES --output_dir /path/to/extracts/`
>
> Above command will extract all tables from specified "filename"
> mysqldump file and extracts tables in compressed format to individual
> files, table-name.sql.gz stored under /path/to/extracts/. The script
> will create the folder /path/to/extracts/ if not exists.
>
> 10. Extract one or more tables from one database in a full-dump:
>
> Consider you have a full dump with multiple databases and you want to
> extract few tables from one database.
>
> Extract single database: `sh mysqldumpsplitter.sh --source filename --extract DB --match_str DBNAME --compression none`
>
> Extract all tables `sh mysqldumpsplitter.sh --source out/DBNAME.sql --extract REGEXP --match_str "(tbl1|tbl2)"` though we can use another option to do this in single command as follows:
>
> `sh mysqldumpsplitter.sh --source filename --extract DBTABLE --match_str "DBNAME.(tbl1|tbl2)" --compression none`
>
> Above command will extract both tbl1 and tbl2 from DBNAME database in
> sql format under folder "out" in current directory.
>
> You can extract single table as follows:
>
> `sh mysqldumpsplitter.sh --source filename --extract DBTABLE --match_str "DBNAME.(tbl1)" --compression none`
>
> 11. Extract all tables from specific database:
>
> `mysqldumpsplitter.sh --source filename --extract DBTABLE --match_str "DBNAME.*" --compression none`
>
> Above command will extract all tables from DBNAME database in sql
> format and store it under "out" directory.
>
> 12. List content of the mysqldump file
>
> `mysqldumpsplitter.sh --source filename --desc`
>
> Above command will list databases and tables from the dump file.

You may later choose to load the files: zcat filename.sql.gz | mysql -uUSER -p -hHOSTNAME

- Also once you extract single table which you think is still bigger, you can use  linux split command with number of lines to further split the dump.
  `split -l 10000 filename.sql`
- That said, if that is your need (coming more often), you might consider using [mydumper](https://launchpad.net/mydumper) which actually creates individual dumps you wont need to split!

Comment: I have to complement you on your bash script. I had a huge database backup and it took me about 60 hours to split the database. I was worried that your script might break but it worked like a charm. Thanks and keep up the good work.

Comment: This was so helpful! Thanks for posting

Answer (score 12):

You say that you don't have access to the second server. But if you have shell access to the first server, where the tables are, you can split your dump by table:

```
for T in `mysql -N -B -e 'show tables from dbname'`; \
   do echo $T; \
   mysqldump [connecting_options] dbname $T \
   | gzip -c > dbname_$T.dump.gz ; \
   done
```

This will create a gzip file for each table.

Another way of splitting the output of mysqldump in separate files is using the --tab option.

```
mysqldump [connecting options] --tab=directory_name dbname
```

where *directory_name* is the name of an empty directory. 
This command creates a .sql file for each table, containing the CREATE TABLE statement, and a .txt file, containing the data, to be restored using LOAD DATA INFILE. I am not sure if phpMyAdmin can handle these files with your particular restriction, though.

Comment: While this may not directly meet OP's needs, it's an awesome way to get individual tables into their own files...for grep etc.

Comment: If any of the tables are written to while this script is running the backup will be in an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 10):

Late reply but was looking for same solution and came across following code from below website:

```
for I in $(mysql -e 'show databases' -s --skip-column-names); do mysqldump $I | gzip > "$I.sql.gz"; done
```

http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2916/backup-all-mysql-databases-to-individual-files

Answer (score 4):

You can split existent file by AWK. It's very quik and simple

Let's split table dump by 'tables' :

```
cat dump.sql | awk 'BEGIN {output = "comments"; }
$data ~ /^CREATE TABLE/ {close(output); output = substr($3,2,length($3)-2); }
{ print $data >> output }';
```

Or you can split dump by 'database'

```
cat backup.sql | awk 'BEGIN {output="comments";} $data ~ /Current Database/ {close(output);output=$4;} {print $data>>output}';
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this.  But it's probably worth noting that `$data` works out as equivalent to `$0` (unless the `data` variable gets set to something with a number).  I don't know how well defined that is across different awks..

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a new version of the SQLDumpSplitter, this time with a proper parser, allowing nice things like INSERTs with many values to be split over files and it is multi platform now: https://philiplb.de/sqldumpsplitter3/

Answer (score 2):

You don't need ssh access to either of your servers. Just a mysql[dump] client is fine.
With the mysql[dump], you can dump your database and import it again.

In your PC, you can do something like:

$ mysqldump -u originaluser -poriginalpassword -h originalhost originaldatabase | mysql -u newuser -pnewpassword -h newhost newdatabase

and you're done. :-)

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can dump individual tables with mysqldump by running `mysqldump database table1 table2 ... tableN`

If none of the tables are too large, that will be enough. Otherwise, you'll have to start splitting the data in the larger tables.

Answer (score 1):

i would recommend the utility bigdump, you can grab it here. http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump.php
this staggers the execution of the dump, in as close as it can manage to your limit, executing whole lines at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://github.com/shenli/mysqldump-hugetable
It will dump data into many small files. Each file contains less or equal MAX_RECORDS records. You can set this parameter in env.sh.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Python script to split a single large sql dump file into separate files, one for each CREATE TABLE statement. It writes the files to a new folder that you specify. If no output folder is specified, it creates a new folder with the same name as the dump file, in the same directory. It works line-by-line, without writing the file to memory first, so it is great for large files.

https://github.com/kloddant/split_sql_dump_file

```
import sys, re, os

if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    raise Exception("""Must be using Python 3.  Try running "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python37-32\\python.exe" split_sql_dump_file.py""")

sqldump_path = input("Enter the path to the sql dump file: ")

if not os.path.exists(sqldump_path):
    raise Exception("Invalid sql dump path.  {sqldump_path} does not exist.".format(sqldump_path=sqldump_path))

output_folder_path = input("Enter the path to the output folder: ") or sqldump_path.rstrip('.sql')

if not os.path.exists(output_folder_path):
    os.makedirs(output_folder_path)

table_name = None
output_file_path = None
smallfile = None

with open(sqldump_path, 'rb') as bigfile:
    for line_number, line in enumerate(bigfile):
        line_string = line.decode("utf-8")
        if 'CREATE TABLE' in line_string.upper():
            match = re.match(r"^CREATE TABLE (?:IF NOT EXISTS )?`(?P<table>\w+)` \($", line_string)
            if match:
                table_name = match.group('table')
                print(table_name)
                output_file_path = "{output_folder_path}/{table_name}.sql".format(output_folder_path=output_folder_path.rstrip('/'), table_name=table_name)
                if smallfile:
                    smallfile.close()
                smallfile = open(output_file_path, 'wb')
        if not table_name:
            continue
        smallfile.write(line)
    smallfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try csplit(1) to cut up the output into the individual tables based on regular expressions (matching the table boundary I would think).

Answer (score 0):

Check out SQLDumpSplitter 2, I just used it to split a 40MB dump with success. You can get it at the link below:

[sqldumpsplitter.com](http://sqldumpsplitter.com)

Hope this help.

Comment: SQLDumpSplitter2 can handle files up to 2 GB only (2 147 483 648 bytes - it uses 32bit signed integer for file size, I think). It could be great to modify this or compile original source code for 64bit, but I'm afraid that source code is probably lost. Otherwise it's a great tool. But many problems with splitting SQL files starts somewhere around 2 GB size.

Comment: Hi there,

I just wanted to let you know that there is a rewrite of that program now available: https://philiplb.de/sqldumpsplitter3/

Answer (score 0):

This [script](http://gadelkareem.com/2012/11/16/use-mysqldump-to-create-separate-files-and-directories-for-databases-and-tables/) should do it:

```
#!/bin/sh

#edit these
USER=""
PASSWORD=""
MYSQLDIR="/path/to/backupdir"

MYSQLDUMP="/usr/bin/mysqldump"
MYSQL="/usr/bin/mysql"

echo - Dumping tables for each DB
databases=`$MYSQL --user=$USER --password=$PASSWORD -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | grep -Ev "(Database|information_schema)"`
for db in $databases; do
    echo - Creating "$db" DB
    mkdir $MYSQLDIR/$db
    chmod -R 777 $MYSQLDIR/$db
    for tb in `$MYSQL  --user=$USER --password=$PASSWORD -N -B -e "use $db ;show tables"`
        do 
            echo -- Creating table $tb
            $MYSQLDUMP --opt  --delayed-insert --insert-ignore --user=$USER --password=$PASSWORD $db $tb | bzip2 -c > $MYSQLDIR/$db/$tb.sql.bz2
    done
    echo
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created MySQLDumpSplitter.java which, unlike bash scripts, works on Windows. It's
available here https://github.com/Verace/MySQLDumpSplitter.

Answer (score 0):

A clarification on the answer of @Vérace :

I specially like the interactive method; you can split a large file in Eclipse. I have tried a 105GB file in Windows successfully:

Just add the MySQLDumpSplitter library to your project:
http://dl.bintray.com/verace/MySQLDumpSplitter/jar/

Quick note on how to import:

```
- In Eclipse, Right click on your project --> Import
- Select "File System" and then "Next"
- Browse the path of the jar file and press "Ok"
- Select (thick) the "MySQLDumpSplitter.jar" file and then "Finish"
- It will be added to your project and shown in the project folder in Package Explorer in Eclipse
- Double click on the jar file in Eclipse (in Package Explorer)
- The "MySQL Dump file splitter" window opens which you can specify the address of your dump file and proceed with split.
```