# Can I restore a single table from a full mysql mysqldump file?

Tags: mysql, backup, restore

I have a mysqldump backup of my mysql database consisting of all of our tables which is about 440 megs. I want to restore the contents of just one of the tables from the mysqldump. Is this possible? Theoretically, I could just cut out the section that rebuilds the table I want but I don't even know how to effectively edit a text document that size.

Comment: FWIW, you could also use [mydumper](https://launchpad.net/mydumper). This creates a logical dump like mysqldump, but it outputs separate files per table, and it can do both the dumping and the loading multi-threaded, so it takes less time.

Comment: We have  https://github.com/kedarvj/mysqldumpsplitter to extract objects you want from the dump.

Answer (score 348, accepted):

You can try to use sed in order to extract only the table you want.

Let say the name of your table is `mytable` and the file `mysql.dump` is the file containing your huge dump:

```
$ sed -n -e '/CREATE TABLE.*`mytable`/,/Table structure for table/p' mysql.dump > mytable.dump
```

This will copy in the file `mytable.dump` what is located between `CREATE TABLE mytable` and the next `CREATE TABLE` corresponding to the next table.

You can then adjust the file `mytable.dump` which contains the structure of the table `mytable`, and the data (a list of `INSERT`).

Comment: That's even nicer than my answer since it takes care of the CREATE TABLE too, but you should search with the backquotes so as not to get another table called "thisismytabletoo".

Comment: True. I was not sure if the table names in all mysql dumps are always surrounded by backquote or if "CREATE TABLE mytable" could also be possible. We can easily adapt the first regexp if we know how the dump looks like.

A second problem could be if the table mytable is not unique (one in the database db1, and another one in the database db2). Both will be exported in the file mytable.dump.
If the table is not unique, we can use the same sed command, first with CREATE DATABASE in order to extract only the right database. Then, use the sed command with CREATE TABLE.

Comment: Yep, JCCyC. This thing did exactly what I needed with zero monkeybusiness. Thank you and uloBasEl so much!

Comment: Sweet!  Remember to add DROP TABLE at the top and remove the DROP TABLE [next table] at the bottom of the file.

Comment: For not adding/removing DROP TABLE, it is more useful to match by `Table structure for table` comment, instead of matching by CREATE TABLE. This will ensure that next table would not be dropped if one forgets to remove its DROP TABLE statement, and allows piping for single-command table restore (gzip | sed | mysql). However, this solution is dependent on mysqldump comment syntax (I don't know how standard it is).

Comment: With Olexa's modification it's perfect:
    sed -n -e '/Table structure for.*`mytable/,/Table structure for/p' whole.sql > mytable.sql

Comment: This answer is better, it includes the DROP TABLE => http://stackoverflow.com/a/15857815/292408

Comment: Remember to add a closing backtick ` after the tablename, otherwise all tables with the same prefix will be matched.

Comment: It works fine also for postgres `$ sed -n -e '/COPY.*mytable/,/COPY/p' pg.dump > mytable.dump` - Thanks!

Comment: Anone know how i can swap mytable for a variable in bash?

```
export VAR=my_table
sed -n -e '/CREATE TABLE.*`$VAR`/,/Table structure for table/p' backup
```

Comment: Thank you!  Worked for a .sql file too.  I just had to edit 1 line to make the import work - /*!40101 SET character_set_client = 'utf8' */; instead of /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;  (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29112716/mysql-error-1231-42000variable-character-set-client-cant-be-set-to-the-val)

Answer (score 160):

I used a modified version of uloBasEI's sed command. It includes the preceding DROP command, and reads until mysql is done dumping data to your table (UNLOCK). Worked for me (re)importing *wp_users* to a bunch of Wordpress sites.

```
sed -n -e '/DROP TABLE.*`mytable`/,/UNLOCK TABLES/p' mydump.sql > tabledump.sql
```

Comment: this is actually a much better solution than the one chosen as the answer, above. Can't believe it didnt' get more upvotes.

Comment: I suggest adding at least backtick quotes to the table name: `\`mytable\`` to avoid matching tables `mytable2` and so on as was in my case.

Comment: Maxim, it didn't work because there was no source file in the example nor stdout and destination file. I edited the example to include these (mydump.sql > tabledump.sql) and it should work now.

Comment: for me sed give wrong file format, must be utf8 but is ansi. text is damaged.

Comment: you just saved my ass

Comment: @user706420 Hmm, are you certain your terminal wasn't to blame? `sed` shouldn't interfere with encoding...

Comment: @rICh this answer is a bit more difficult to understand and it requires good sql dump strucutre. Also, if you want add DROP and other additions, you can derive this from uloBasEl's answer easily.

Comment: For those with SQL files not containing the `DROP TABLE` (my MySQL dump did not have this) may want to use:`sed -n -e '/-- Table structure for table ``<Table Name>/,/UNLOCK TABLES/p' <SQL File> > table.sql`

This makes use of the table comments provided before each table in a MySQl dump, and ensures lines like `/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;` get included.

Comment: Thanks @WestonGanger. t I believe you are correct.  The command should be ```sed -n -e '/-- Table structure for table `<Table Name>`/,/UNLOCK TABLES/p' <SQL File> > table.sql```

Comment: To enchance this ever more: For large dump files, you can tell sed to stop once the match from/to has been found by adding the `q` command like this:  ```sed -n -e '/DROP TABLE.*`mytable`/,/UNLOCK TABLES/{p;/UNLOCK TABLES/q}' mydump.sql > tabledump.sql```

Comment: What about foreign key check? How to disable it properly - `sed` will skip that statement?

Answer (score 63):

This can be done more easily? This is how I did it:

Create a temporary database (e.g. restore):

> mysqladmin -u root -p create restore

Restore the full dump in the temp database:

> mysql -u root -p --one-database restore < fulldump.sql

Dump the table you want to recover:

> mysqldump restore mytable > mytable.sql

Import the table in another database:

> mysql -u root -p database < mytable.sql

Comment: This is what most people need.

Comment: According to [this edit suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9403385), you should add the "--one-database" parameter, to make sure you restore only **one** database and don't destroy everything else.

Comment: For really huge db it is can very weird - restore 150 GB of data for one table of 100 MB.

Comment: I just ran this without "--one-database" and it still merged tables just fine. It didn't remove my existing tables.

Comment: Very bad practice! I had few DBs in dump, and trying to restore only one, deleted all others.

Comment: can be done from shell entirely, very easy. no need for editing files or sql knowledge.

Comment: @AndreyP I'm using mariadb it worked fine for me, sql file originating from table dump didn't have any drop statement for any other table or db itself. Which version of mysql were you using?

Comment: @S.L.Barth I'm wondering if this happens only when there are a multiple db dumps in single file

Comment: This restored a database with a default collocation of latin something, while my original db was UTF-8, I hope I don't run into issues

Comment: The table name could be case sensitive. Check the name of the table in the database by running `use restore;` and `show tables;` in the MySQL Command-Line Client.

Comment: This is very dangerous if the backup contains multiple databases or if it contains a full dump for one database with a different name than the one used for the temporary database. The --one-database option should be used always to avoid problems; adding that to the answer.

Comment: This is not 'more easily' at all.  It requires 3 major steps which are significant if you have a database that is anything but a few records.  Using the sed method above is a clever and neat way to achieve the result, unless of course someone is too lazy to figure out how it works?

Answer (score 13):

A simple solution would be to simply create a dump of just the table you wish to restore separately.  You can use the mysqldump command to do so with the following syntax:

```
mysqldump -u [user] -p[password] [database] [table] > [output_file_name].sql
```

Then import it as normal, and it will only import the dumped table.

Answer (score 9):

One way or another, any process doing that will have to go through the entire text of the dump and parse it in some way. I'd just grep for

```
INSERT INTO `the_table_i_want`
```

and pipe the output into mysql. Take a look at the first table in the dump before, to make sure you're getting the INSERT's the right way.

Edit: OK, got the formatting right this time.

Comment: I'm dumb for not immediately thinking of grepping it. Grep saves my bacon every day, it seems. The other two suggestions were also bang-up ones and totally what I would have done without the wonders of grep available. Thank you all!

Comment: If you think you love grep, when you learn awk you'll become its happy sex slave: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awk

Answer (score 9):

You should try [bryn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15857815), but with the `` ` `` delimiter, otherwise you will also extract the tables having a prefix or a suffix, this is what I usually do:

```
sed -n -e '/DROP TABLE.*`mytable`/,/UNLOCK TABLES/p' dump.sql > mytable.sql
```

Also for testing purposes, you may want to change the table name before importing:

```
sed -n -e 's/`mytable`/`mytable_restored`/g' mytable.sql > mytable_restored.sql
```

To import you can then use the MySQL command:

```
mysql -u root -p'password' mydatabase < mytable_restore.sql
```

Answer (score 9):

1. Backup

   ```
   $ mysqldump -A | gzip > mysqldump-A.gz
   ```
2. Restore single table

   ```
   $ mysql -e "truncate TABLE_NAME" DB_NAME
   $ zgrep ^"INSERT INTO \`TABLE_NAME" mysqldump-A.gz | mysql DB_NAME
   ```

Answer (score 4):

One possible way to deal with this is to restore to a temporary database, and dump just that table from the temporary database.  Then use the new script.

Answer (score 4):

```
sed -n -e '/-- Table structure for table `my_table_name`/,/UNLOCK TABLES/p' database_file.sql > table_file.sql
```

This is a better solution than some of the others above because not all SQL dumps contain a `DROP TABLE` statement. This one will work will all kinds of dumps.

Answer (score 3):

This tool may be is what you want: tbdba-restore-mysqldump.pl

https://github.com/orczhou/dba-tool/blob/master/tbdba-restore-mysqldump.pl

e.g. Restore a table from database dump file:

> tbdba-restore-mysqldump.pl -t yourtable -s yourdb -f backup.sql

Answer (score 3):

This may help too.

```
# mysqldump -u root -p database0 > /tmp/database0.sql
# mysql -u root -p -e 'create database database0_bkp'
# mysql -u root -p database0_bkp < /tmp/database0.sql
# mysql -u root -p database0 -e 'insert into database0.table_you_want select * from database0_bkp.table_you_want'
```

Comment: This is my favorite answer so far.  It's clean (i.e., all done within MySQL) and doesn't require manipulation with sed.

Answer (score 3):

Table should present with same structure in both dump and database.

```
`zgrep -a ^"INSERT INTO \`table_name" DbDump-backup.sql.tar.gz | mysql -u<user> -p<password> database_name`
```

or

```
`zgrep -a ^"INSERT INTO \`table_name" DbDump-backup.sql | mysql -u<user> -p<password> database_name`
```

Answer (score 1):

Most modern text editors should be able to handle a text file that size, if your system is up to it.

Anyway, I had to do that once very quickly and i didnt have time to find any tools.  I set up a new MySQL instance, imported the whole backup and then spit out just the table I wanted.

Then I imported that table into the main database.

It was tedious but rather easy. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The 'sed' solutions mentioned earlier are nice but as mentioned not 100% secure

- You may have INSERT commands with data containing:
  ... CREATE TABLE...(whatever)...mytable...
- or even the exact string "CREATE TABLE `mytable`;" 
  if you are storing DML commands for instance!

(and if the table is huge you don't want to check that manually)

I would verify the exact syntax of the dump version used, and have a more restrictive pattern search:

Avoid ".*" and use "^" to ensure we start at the begining of the line.
And I'd prefer to grab the initial 'DROP'

All in all, this works better for me:

```
sed -n -e '/^DROP TABLE IF EXISTS \`mytable\`;/,/^UNLOCK TABLES;/p' mysql.dump > mytable.dump
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use vi editor. Type:

```
vi -o mysql.dump mytable.dump
```

to open both whole dump `mysql.dump` and a new file `mytable.dump`.
Find the appropriate insert into line by pressing `/` and then type a phrase, for example: "insert into `mytable`", then copy that line using `yy`. Switch to next file by `ctrl+w` then `down arrow key`, paste the copied line with `pp`. Finally save the new file by typing `:wq` and quite vi editor by `:q`.

Note that if you have dumped the data using multiple inserts you can copy (yank) all of them at once using `Nyy` in which `N` is the number of lines to be copied.

I have done it with a file of 920 MB size.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a few options, which were incredibly slow. This split a 360GB dump into its tables in a few minutes:

[How do I split the output from mysqldump into smaller files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132902/how-do-i-split-the-output-from-mysqldump-into-smaller-files#answer-9949414)

Answer (score 0):

Get a decent text editor like Notepad++ or Vim (if you're already proficient with it).  Search for the table name and you should be able to highlight just the CREATE, ALTER, and INSERT commands for that table.  It may be easier to navigate with your keyboard rather than a mouse.  And I would make sure you're on a machine with plenty or RAM so that it will not have a problem loading the entire file at once.  Once you've highlighted and copied the rows you need, it would be a good idea to back up just the copied part into it's own backup file and then import it into MySQL.

Comment: This is actually really easy to do and understandable even by beginners. I do not know, why this is downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

The chunks of SQL are blocked off with "Table structure for table `my_table`" and "Dumping data for table `my_table`."

You can use a Windows command line as follows to get the line numbers for the various sections. Adjust the searched string as needed.

find /n "for table `" sql.txt

The following will be returned:

---------- SQL.TXT

[4384]-- Table structure for table `my_table`

[4500]-- Dumping data for table `my_table`

[4514]-- Table structure for table `some_other_table`

... etc.

That gets you the line numbers you need... now, if I only knew how to use them... investigating.

Answer (score -4):

**You can import single table using terminal line as given below.**
Here import single user table into specific database.

`mysql -u root -p -D my_database_name  < var/www/html/myproject/tbl_user.sql`

Comment: that imports everything related to that database from the sql file. This question was about extracting a single table from a full database dump. useful ... but not related to this question

Answer (score -4):

I admire some of the ingenuity here, but there is literally no reason to use `sed` at all to address the OP's question.

The comment "use --one-database" is the correct answer, built into MySQL/MariaDB. No need for third-party hacks.

`mysql -u root -p databasename --one-database < localhost.sql` will just import the desired database.

I also found in some cases, when using this to import a series of databases, it would create the next database in the list for me (but not put anything in it). Not sure why it did that, but it made the restore easier.

With this command, enter the password interactively and it will import the requested database.

Comment: Except that the OP asked about restoring a single table from a single database dump, not restoring a single database from an 'all databases' dump?