# How to import a single table in to mysql database using command line

Tags: mysql, import

I had successfully imported a database using command line, but now my pain area is how to import a single table with its data to the existing database using command line.

Comment: export single table only and import

Comment: See also this duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1013852/385571 with its more relevant answers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I restore a single table from a full mysql mysqldump file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013852/can-i-restore-a-single-table-from-a-full-mysql-mysqldump-file)

Answer (score 371):

Linux :

In command line

```
 mysql -u username -p databasename < path/example.sql
```

put your table in example.sql

Import / Export for single table:

1. Export table schema

   ```
   mysqldump -u username -p databasename tableName > path/example.sql
   ```

   This will create a file named `example.sql` at the path mentioned and write the `create table` sql command to create table `tableName`.
2. Import a single table into database

   ```
   mysql -u username -p databasename < path/example.sql
   ```

   This command needs an sql file containing data in form of `insert` statements for table `tableName`. All the `insert` statements will be executed and the data will be loaded.

Comment: the -u was missed ;) mysqldump -u username -p databasename tableName > path/example.sql

Comment: For importing you don't need to use mysql dump.
mysql -u username -p databasename tableName < path/example.sql

It should do your job

Comment: The `tableName` name does not needed for all MySQL versions and it produces errors, so you may need to omit it!

Comment: I was getting a syntax error until I realized to be in bash and not mysql when executing.

Comment: This would work only if I have access to the database from which I can export a specific table.  However, if I have a full dump of the database and want to cherry-pick the table(s) to be imported, this solution won't work.  The linked post [Can I restore a single table from a full mysql mysqldump file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1013852/6862601) addresses that issue.

Comment: For importing table following is worked for me.
`mysql -u username -p -D dbname < tableName.sql`

Answer (score 49):

**Export:**

```
mysqldump --user=root databasename > whole.database.sql
mysqldump --user=root databasename onlySingleTableName > single.table.sql
```

**Import**:

Whole **database**:

```
mysql --user=root wholedatabase < whole.database.sql
```

Single **table**:

```
mysql --user=root databasename < single.table.sql
```

Answer (score 23):

**Importing the Single Table**

To import a single table into an existing database you would use the following command:

```
mysql -u username -p -D database_name < tableName.sql
```

***Note:It is better to use full path of the sql file tableName.sql***

Answer (score 6):

First of all, login to your database and check whether the database table which you want to import is not available on your database.

If it is available, delete the table using the command. Else it will throw an error while importing the table.

```
DROP TABLE Table_Name;
```

Then, move to the folder in which you have the `.sql` file to import and run the following command from your terminal

```
mysql -u username -p  databasename  < yourtable.sql
```

The terminal will ask you to enter the password. Enter it and check the database.

Answer (score 5):

**Command Line**

Import / Export for single table:

**Exporting  table schema**

```
 -> mysqldump -u your_user_name -p your_database_name table_name > test.sql
```

This will create a file named test.sql  and  creates table sql command to create table table_name.

**Importing data into table**

```
 -> mysql -u your_user_name -p database_name table_name < test.sql
```

Make sure your test.sql file is in the same directory, if not navigate through the path and then run the command.

Comment: You do not need to specify the table name in the command line, as the exported SQL file has the relevant call to create the table.  All you need is `mysql -u your_user_name -p database_name < test.sql`.

Comment: Here's an example from an exported table, ` 22 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `account_product_prices`;
 23 /*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
 24 /*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
 25 CREATE TABLE `account_product_prices` (`

Answer (score 4):

It works correctly...

```
C:\>mysql>bin>mysql -u USERNAME DB_NAME < tableNameFile.sql
```

please note .sql file specified your current database..

Answer (score 4):

If you're in the pwd of an SQL dump and you need a table from that, do this:

```
sed -n '/-- Table structure for table `'TableNameTo_GrabHere'`/,/-- Table/{ /^--.*$/d;p }' dump_file_to_extract_from.sql > table_name_here.sql
```

Then just import the table you extracted from the above into the needed database

Answer (score 3):

We can import single table using CMD as below:

```
D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin>mysql -h hostname -u username -p passowrd databasename < filepath
```

Answer (score 2):

- It would be combination of `EXPORT INTO OUTFILE` and `LOAD DATA INFILE`
- You need to export that single table with `EXPORT INTO OUTFILE`, this will export table data to a file. You can import that particular table using `LOAD DATA INFILE`
- Refer [doc1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) , [doc2](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html)

Answer (score 2):

Also its working. In command form

```
cd C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\bin //hit enter
mysql -u -p databasename //-u=root,-p=blank
```

Answer (score 2):

you can  do it in mysql command instead of linux command.
1.login your mysql.
2.excute this in mysql command:
`use DATABASE_NAME;`
`SET autocommit=0 ; source ABSOLUTE_PATH/TABLE_SQL_FILE.sql ; COMMIT ;`

Answer (score 2):

if you already have the desired table on your database, first delete it and then run the command below:

```
 mysql -u username -p  databasename  < yourtable.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

**From server to local(Exporting)**

```
mysqldump -u username -p db_name table_name > path/filename.sql;
mysqldump -u root -p remotelab welcome_ulink > 
/home_local/ladmin/kakalwar/base/welcome_ulink.sql;
```

**From local to server(Importing)**

```
mysql -u username -p -D databasename < path/x/y/z/welcome_queue.sql
mysql -u root -p -D remotelab < 
/home_local/ladmin/kakalwar/instant_status/db_04_12/welcome_queue.sql
```

Comment: For beginers please note u have to operate from terminal not inside the mysql

after hitting the command it will ask for the password the db_password

Answer (score 1):

To import a particular table in database follow below command.
Here table_name.sql is dump of taht particular table that you are going to import

```
mysql -u root -p database_name table_name < table_name.sql
```

To export a particular table from database follow below command.

```
mysqldump -u root -p database_name table_name > table_name.sql
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below command to import a single table into the database on RDS

> mysql -h rds_end_point -u username -p databasename < example.sql

Answer (score 0):

```
-> mysql -h host -u user -p database_name table_name < test_table.sql
```

Comment: the table_name param is not available in latest mysql versions

Answer (score 0):

Using a temporary database could be a solution depending on the size of the database.

```
mysql -u [username] -p -e "create database tempdb"
mysql -u [username] -p tempdb < db.sql
mysqldump -u [username] -p tempdb _table_to_import_ > table_to_import.sql
mysql -u [username] -p maindb < table_to_import.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

To import a table into database, if table is already exist then add this line in your sql file `DROP TABLE IF EXIST 'table_name'` and run command `mysql -u username -p database_name < import_sql_file.sql`.
Please verify the sql file path before execute the command.

Answer (score 0):

Open the backup file in the VScode and search the table name copy the create table  and insert command for the table. Copy and execute those two commands in the database where it is required.

Answer (score -1):

First of all take backup of your both database, step 2 select table which you want to export now select export button now download sql file now you have to import into another database simply select database and then import sql file ... simple and easy.