# Import/export tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

Want to import users from a table(re_user) to another table(pg_users).
Can you help me?
Thnx.

```
INSERT INTO `pg_users`(`id`, `fname`, `sname`, `status`, `confirm`, `login`, 
`password`, `lang_id`, `email`, `date_birthday`, `date_last_seen`, 
`date_registration`, `root_user`, `guest_user`, `login_count`, `active`, 
`show_info`, `phone`, `user_type`, `access`, `version_message_count`, `rating`,
`about_me`, `social_data`, `date_modified`)

SELECT `id`, `fname`, `sname`, `status`, `confirm`, `login`, `password`, `lang_id`,
`email`, `date_birthday`, `date_last_seen`, `date_registration`, `root_user`,
`guest_user`, `login_count`, `active`, `show_info`, `phone`, `user_type`,
`access`,`version_message_count`, `rating`, `about_me`, `social_data`, 
`date_modified` FROM `re_user` WHERE 1
```

Comment: Please be more descriptive by providing any errors you are experiencing and/or the results you are currently getting or simply, why isn't this working for you.

Comment: Please check the documentation first: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: You have an issue with your where clause of select query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to import a single table in to mysql database using command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387619/how-to-import-a-single-table-in-to-mysql-database-using-command-line)

Comment: INSERT INTO `pg_users`(`id`, `fname`, `sname`, `status`, `confirm`, `login`, `password`, `lang_id`, `email`, `date_birthday`, `date_last_seen`, `date_registration`, `root_user`, `guest_user`, `login_count`, `active`, `show_info`, `phone`, `user_type`, `access`, `version_message_count`, `rating`, `about_me`, `social_data`, `date_modified`)
SELECT re_user  WHERE re_user > 100;

Comment: You can edit your post to include your updated information.  No need to add them as comments. Just an FYI. Makes it easier for people to help you. :)

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE re_user > 100' at line 2

Comment: The information in the error you received and what you posted don't match up.  The where clause in your error is different than the where clause in your post.  It will be challenging to get to the bottom of this, if it is not clear as to what code you are really trying to fix.

Comment: I have 2 DB.Want to transfer users from table re_user of first DB to table pg_users from second DB.

Comment: Ahhhh, that is the description I was looking for!

Comment: Have an issue.#1142 - SELECT command denied to user 'DB'@'localhost' for table 're_user'

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you disclosed in your comments, that you want to insert data into a table by pulling it from a table in another database, you must be specific as to which database this information is coming from, and going to.  Update the `DESTINATION_SCHEMA_NAME` and the `SOURCE_SCHEMA_NAME` in my example below and that should resolve the issue.  Also, if you are copying everything, there is no need for the where clause in your select statement.

```
INSERT INTO `DESTINATION_SCHEMA_NAME.`pg_users`(`id`, `fname`, `sname`, `status`, `confirm`, `login`, 
`password`, `lang_id`, `email`, `date_birthday`, `date_last_seen`, 
`date_registration`, `root_user`, `guest_user`, `login_count`, `active`, 
`show_info`, `phone`, `user_type`, `access`, `version_message_count`, `rating`,
`about_me`, `social_data`, `date_modified`)

SELECT `id`, `fname`, `sname`, `status`, `confirm`, `login`, `password`, `lang_id`,
`email`, `date_birthday`, `date_last_seen`, `date_registration`, `root_user`,
`guest_user`, `login_count`, `active`, `show_info`, `phone`, `user_type`,
`access`,`version_message_count`, `rating`, `about_me`, `social_data`, 
`date_modified` FROM `SOURCE_SCHEMA_NAME`.`re_user`
```

Comment: Have an issue.#1142 - SELECT command denied to user 'DB'@'localhost' for table 're_user'

Comment: that means that whatever database user you are using, doesn't have access to that database/table.  If you still wish to copy data from one database into another, your user account needs to have access to both databases and to both tables in those databases.

Comment: Let me tell you more,i have a realestate website and want to transfer users and listings to another website.What is the best method?        Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you have the ability to, you can grant access to the database that the user doesn't have access to so that you can run the insert command, and than remove that access after to ensure that user account remains secure.

Comment: If you want to transfer more than one table, you can try using a program called "MySQL Workbench" to connect to the source database, export the data to an SQL file, and then connect to your destination database, and import those records.

Comment: I will download now MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'date_created' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do that.

**Command Line**

Import / Export for single table:

**Exporting  table schema**

```
 -> mysqldump -u your_user_name -p your_database_name table_name > test.sql
```

This will create a file named test.sql  and  creates table sql command to create table table_name.

**Importing data into table**

```
 -> mysql -u your_user_name -p database_name table_name < test.sql
```

Make sure your test.sql file is in the same directory, if not navigate through the path and then run the command.