# How to insert a tables 600mln rows into another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

setup:
Primary server, collection point
4 secondairy servers, data import

import servers have more tables. Every database about 500GB big with together more then 15 billion records

We are running into a problem when trying to import tables from an imported database into the primary server.

How would I go about this?

Comment: you can replicate the needed tables.

Comment: the tables are build up the same. However We want to combine them together.

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5387653/4421474

Comment: did not understand. You can combine with replication. Or they have different data on both sides?

Comment: @sidux different data on both sides

Comment: @alex windows server, no linux.

Comment: @JBom mysql commands almost the same for linux and windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SSIS`

Create regular data flow with 2 components - OLE DB Source and OLE DB Destination (I assume you are using MS SQL Server, in general, use whatever components your company uses to connect to the DB).

In case of 2 DBs, create 2 connection managers, each pointing to its DB. Point OLE DB Source to first connection manager configured to point to source of data, and OLE DB Destination to second connection manager configured to point to destination DB.

Now point OLE DB Source to the source table in source DB, leave all the fields intact. Connect source and destination components with green arrow originally going out of source component. Now point OLE DB Destination to the destination table in target DB. Double-click destination, go to mappings and make sure they are correct (SSIS tries to map automatically using strick name matching), otherwise (in case names are different) connect source and destination fields manually. That's it, you just don't provide mappings for the fields which cannot be accommodated by destination table.

Alternatively, you can leave out the columns you don't need at source component - double-click it, go to Columns and uncheck columns you don't need.

Better place to ask this question is : https://dba.stackexchange.com/