# How to skip a table when restoring mysql database?

Tags: mysql, restore

I  have a big mySQL database dump named forum.sql. I want to restore only one table, but when I restore the full database, it takes a long time to import the "post" table.

Is there any option to restore this database skipping the "post" table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013852/can-i-restore-a-single-table-from-a-full-mysql-mysqldump-file

Answer (score 4):

If you are restoring from a dump file, you can easily build a new dumpfile without this table, just by writting down the line numbers.

Initial line

```
> grep dumpfile.sql -ne "Dumping data for table \`avoid_tablename\`" -m 1
43:-- Dumping data for table `avoid_tablename`
```

Total lines

```
> wc -l dumpfile.sql
63 dumpfile.sql
```

Make a new file

```
> head -n 43 dumpfile.sql > dumpfile-lite.sql
> tail -n 20 dumpfile.sql >> dumpfile-lile.sql
```

20 comes from substracting 63 - 43

not clean, but usefull

Comment: This can be done without knowing the total lines in the file. tail -n +43 < input_file > output_file

It is helpful when dealing with HUGE files

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, extract the table(s) that need to be restored from `fulldump.sql`  using `sed`:

```sh
sed -n -e '/CREATE TABLE.*tableName1/,/CREATE TABLE/p' fulldump.sql > temp.sql
sed -n -e '/CREATE TABLE.*tableName2/,/CREATE TABLE/p' fulldump.sql >> temp.sql
```

...etc

Now restore from `temp.sql`.

Answer (score 1):

### Restore a single table

First, do the restore with zero inserts:

```
cat dump.sql | grep -v '^INSERT INTO' | mysql -u <user> -p<pw> <dbname>
```

Using `grep -v` here will exclude any statements matching the pattern. The pattern in this case uses `^` to match at the beginning of a line. The result should be a restored schema with zero data.

Next, restore only your desired `INSERT` statements:

```
cat dump.sql | grep '^INSERT INTO \\\`<table>\\\`' | mysql -u <user> -p<pw> <dbname>
```

That will restore data only for the table named `<table>`. Note the triple backslashes. You need a backslash to escape a backtick and then you need to escape the backslash with 2 more backslashes.

### Restore everything except one table

Another technique I use all the time when I want to restore an entire database but exclude the data from a table or two is this... You can filter out any unwanted `INSERT` statements by passing your dump through a filter before pushing into the db. Here's an example using `grep` as the filter:

```
nohup sh -c "cat dump.sql | grep -v 'INSERT INTO \\\`<table>\\\`' | mysql -u <user> -p<pw> <dbname>" &
```

The `nohup` command will keep the `sh` command running even if you log out of your shell. That can be pretty handy if you have a large dump file that will take quite some time to restore.

The `-v` flag for `grep` will exclude anything matching the pattern.

The `&` at the end will send the command to the background.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no.

You would have to manually edit the `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements of the undesired table out of the dump file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it. But you can dump tables separately when necessary, using `--tables` myqsldump option. So, you can generate a dump for `post` table and another dump for the remaining tables.

Example:

```
mysqldump -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD --tables TABLE_NAME database_name > TABLE_NAME.sql
```

Comment: thanks for reply i know i can dump only table but i want restore database else table

Answer (score 0):

You could alter your dump statement so that it uses ignore table? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_ignore-table