# Backup and Restore Single Schema/Table

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Is there a way to backup or restore a specific schema or table on a Cloud SQL server?  Backing up the entire set of data, but then being able to restore only certain schemas or tables would be very helpful for multi-tenant systems.

Answer (score 0):

Not via backup/restore. You can [export](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/admin-api/v1beta3/instances/export) a specific schema or table to Google Cloud Storage, but that's probably not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud SQL use MySQL database with some limitations. You can check out the unsupported features and functions at the following link:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#supportmysqlfeatures

With this in mind any backup/restore tool that are being used for MySQL should work for Google Cloud SQL as well. Using mysqldump for import/export of Cloud SQL is covered at this document:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/import-export

You can use mysqldump to backup specific table or backup entire database and restore only specific tables using the solutions offered in these links:

[Can I restore a single table from a full mysql mysqldump file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013852/can-i-restore-a-single-table-from-a-full-mysql-mysqldump-file)

[How to take backup of a single table in a MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682916/how-to-backup-a-single-table-in-a-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

You can restore the backup to a different instance and then replace the data on the original instance with the data from the backup instance.