# Google cloud SQL backup ignore certain tables

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Is there a way to ignore certain tables when google cloud takes backup of MySQL data (second generation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a backup is performed on a Cloud SQL Second Generation instance, there is no way of selecting which tables you want to save and/or ignore there. Have a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103529/backup-and-restore-single-schema-table) which might be helpful for you and mentions backup/restore tools that work with Cloud SQL.