# MySQL ERROR 1231 (42000):Variable 'character_set_client' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'

Tags: mysql

I've a `MySQL 5.0.84` running in a Slackware 13.0 `Staging` server and wanted to copy a single table to another server which was built to use Ubuntu 14.04 OS for some other testing. I've taken a `mysqldump` of that table and copied to the `testing server`. I get the following error when I try to restore the dump file.

`ERROR 1231 (42000):Variable 'character_set_client' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'`

Please help me how to fix this error. Thanks!

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I did some search in internet and fixed it finally.

Added the following text at the beginning of the mysqldump file and the restore was successful.

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

Comment: This shows an issue when I put @@, when I generated the dump file using phpMyAdmin there was only one @. Any ideas ?

Comment: Thanks. This fixed it for me as well. On Ubuntu 16.04, fresh install, if that helps anyone else.

Comment: Where can i find the mysqldump?

Comment: @nethken you mean the mysqldump command or the actual database backup taken by mysqldump command? The dump file would be in the directory where you mentioned at the end of mysqldump command.

Comment: Noted that those lines are wrapped into `/*` and `*/` will not be interpreted as *comment* and they will work as well.

Comment: in my case I added the lines as shared above to the top of the sql fie and had to remove the lines added at the end of the SQL file by PHPadmin.

Comment: I was getting this in WAMP & above solution didn't work, Later, I increased the innodb_lock_wait_timeout import was successful right away

Comment: Thanks for your input @Manny, Your answer is perfectly worked for me.
The Same 10 line already exists in my SQL dump, but the problem is, before this 10 line, the below code was added. If I remove this below code also. The SQL dump is working.
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.6.40, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: my_db
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version 5.6.40

Comment: Why Mysql doesn't add this automatically?

Answer (score 24):

I have modified

```
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

to

```
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = 'utf8' */;
```

in the dump file after the code for creating table.

Comment: Confimed, it needs to be 'utf8'.

Answer (score 17):

Try to make the maximum allowed packet size arbitrarily high temporarily by typing in:

```
mysql> set global max_allowed_packet=10000000000;
```

/via http://injustfiveminutes.com/2013/02/14/errors-restoring-mysql-database-dump-on-wamp-environment/

Comment: may also want to run the `mysql` client with the `--max_allowed_packet=64M` (or higher) option!

Answer (score 8):

on my way,open the .sql file,in the end ,do del:

```
  /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
  /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
  /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

and source it again,then work well for me!

Comment: this has really helped as you had clearly added the missing of 'CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT' whereas the rest of them seemed to have modified the value of the 'OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT'. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Well, thanks to all the answers, It just helped me solving my issue. But copying and pasting codes from above didn't work for me. So, I exported sql file which was already in my database and from there I took the code and added the following to the beginning of my sql file to import

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.7.0
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Aug 16, 2017 at 07:24 AM
-- Server version: 10.1.25-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 7.1.7

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
```

Because this top section was missing in my sql document. Then the import was successful. I hope this helps someone else too.

Answer (score 2):

I worked for me by adding these 3 lines at the start of the SQL dump file.

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed from

```
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
```

to

```
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
```

it worked for me