# MySQL Wordpress Error? Site Migration Issues

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, server

Just started to upload site from localhost to my server. I have been following this tutorial

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/

I have done everything listed here including updating URL in wp_options and setting database username and password. however I had one error when importing mysql database.

SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT

## 1231 - Variable 'character_set_client' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'

I ignored this as it seemed the database had imported fine. However upon viewing the site it looks as if wordpress and my website have no stylesheets? and any other page besides the index breaks completely and shows an "internal server error" message. Here is the link

http://s654725277.websitehome.co.uk/

Comment: I'm not sure you can blame the database. The error 500 indicates that something failed within your Web Server (line 22). Check your php code at that line and add it to your question.

Comment: Seems to be duplicate issue like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29112716/mysql-error-1231-42000variable-character-set-client-cant-be-set-to-the-val