# PHPMyAdmin database exports always cause MySQL #1231 error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I backup (export) Wordpress databases from production and import them into a development environment on a semi-daily basis. I use PHPMyAdmin to accomplish that and am forever haunted by this one error. Each time I try to import a database I get the following error:

> Sql Query:  /*!40101 SET
>   CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */
>
> My SQL said:
>   1231 - Variable 'character_set_client' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'

`SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT` is a line that PHPMyadmin automatically appends to all exports, but apparently the OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT variable is not defined within the outputted SQL file. The collation is always set correctly for the databases I am trying to export and the "Character set of the file:" option is also set appropriately. I'm at a loss as to why the `OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT` variable ends up with a value of NULL. Is there a way to fix this or at the very least prevent PHPMyAdmin from appending this line to exports?

Edit: I am aware that someone else [asked a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29112716/mysql-error-1231-42000variable-character-set-client-cant-be-set-to-the-val). However, the answer they accepted does not offer any explanation why this issue is happening nor does it present a viable solution to my question.

Comment: possible dublicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29112716/mysql-error-1231-42000variable-character-set-client-cant-be-set-to-the-val](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29112716/mysql-error-1231-42000variable-character-set-client-cant-be-set-to-the-val)

Comment: That question does deal with a similar problem but does not provide a sufficient answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL ERROR 1231 (42000):Variable 'character\_set\_client' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29112716/mysql-error-1231-42000variable-character-set-client-cant-be-set-to-the-val)