# Getting error while reading sql file using sequelize.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize.js to read a sql file but I kept getting error with  sql conditional comment.

I have a large raw sql file that over 2000 lines. It failed if I just pass the whole file to the sequlize.query() function, so instead I split the query with ";" and make it an array then use promise to iterate it in order.

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbName, userName, password, packageJsonDbConfig.options);
let promises = [];
let queries = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'data.sql'));
let splitQueries = queries.toString().replace(/^\s*[\r\n]/gm, '').split(';');
splitQueries.forEach((splitQuery) => {
    promises.push(sequelize.query(splitQuery));
});
Promise.seq(promises.map(p => p.catch((err) => console.log(err))));
```

I kept getting {Variable 'collation_connection' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'} for the following sql conditional comment

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

And

```
Executing (default): --
-- Dumping data for table `TeamMatchScores`
--
LOCK TABLES `TeamMatchScores` WRITE
Executing (default): /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `TeamMatchScores` DISABLE KEYS */
{ SequelizeDatabaseError: Table 'arthurmurray.teammatchentries' doesn't exist }
```

for the following sql statement

```
--
-- Table structure for table `TeamMatchEntries`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `TeamMatchEntries`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `TeamMatchEntries` (
    `TeamMatchEntryID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `EventID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `TeamName` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `TeamStudioID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `TeamID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `ScoreType` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `TeamOrder` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `TeamMatchEntries`
--

LOCK TABLES `TeamMatchEntries` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `TeamMatchEntries` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `TeamMatchEntries` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;"
```

Comment: See if any of the suggestions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29112716/mysql-error-1231-42000variable-character-set-client-cant-be-set-to-the-val help you, same basic question.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because the statements need to be executed sequentially. See code snippet for how it is done.

```
rebuildViews: (sqlz) => {
try {
  var sql_string = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './views.sql')).toString().trim();
  sql_string = sql_string.replace(/--.*|\n|\t/g, ' ').trim();
  let arr = sql_string.replace(/^\s*[\r\n]/gm, '').split(';');


  // remove empty statements
  arr = arr.filter((el) => el != '');
  arr = arr.map((el) => el + ';');

  //   console.log(arr);
  // create a function that will run the stmt for each stmt
  arr = arr.map((el) => sqlz.query(el));

  // execute the stmt sequentially. Note that Promise.resolve() is the seed
  arr.reduce((p, fn) => p.then(fn), Promise.resolve());
} catch (error) {
  logger.error('could not rebuild the views');
}
```

},