# how to restore particular database from .sql file

Tags: mysql

I did mysqldump for `--all-databases` and after some software updation on my machine the one database has deleted. so, How to restore that particular database form .sql file?

```
.sql file contain mysqump for all database.
```

pleased suggest something

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I restore a single table from a full mysql mysqldump file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013852/can-i-restore-a-single-table-from-a-full-mysql-mysqldump-file)

Answer (score 0):

When I've done this in the past I've used Workbench.

[image]

The SQL should contain the code to re-create the schemas and tables, along with the data.