# How to extract text between multiple parentheses on a single line in MySQL dump file

Tags: mysql, shell, sed, extract

I have a MySQL dump file containing several tables.  I already have a [SED command to extract one single table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013852/can-i-restore-a-single-table-from-a-full-mysql-mysqldump-file).

Now I need to know how to extract only the records associated with a specific unit_id. The format is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (1,999,'sometext'), (2,999,'othertext'),(3,997,'text here'),(4,123,'a string'), ...
```

Where 999 is the unit id (there can be multiple records for a single unit id)

My desired result is:

```
999,'sometext'
999,'othertext'
...
```

... for every entry where 999 (or any specific number I choose) appears in the second column.

I tried using sed to select the values between parentheses, like this:

```
sed -n 's/\((.*,999,.*)\)/\1/p' < result.sql
```

Where 999 is the id I'm searching for.

but it returns nothing.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was representing my desired ID with the placeholder [desired_id]. There are no square brackets in the actual expression.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question accordingly

Comment: Edited per request.

Answer (score 2):

`Sed` cannot output the multiple matching results in the same line at a time.
As a workaround we can split the input line at an appropriate punctuation into multiple lines
as a preprocessing.

Would you try the following:

```
sed 's/), *(/)\'$'\n''(/g' result.sql | sed -n 's/.*,\(999,.*\)).*/\1/p'
```

Output:

```
999,'sometext'
999,'othertext'
```

- The first `sed` command `s/), *(/)\'$'\n''(/g'` finds a comma between
  a closing paren and an opening paren then replace it with a newline.
  (It assumes you are running `bash`).
- The next `sed` command `'s/.*,\(999,.*\)).*/\1/p'`extracts your desired
  values.

Alternatively `grep` with `-P` option (perl-compatible regex support)
will also work.

```
grep -Po '(?<=,)999,.*?(?=\))' result.sql
```

- The pattern `(?<=,)` is a zero-width lookbehind assertion which matches
  a leading comma without including it in the result.
- The pattern `.*?` avoids the `greedy` match.
- The pattern `(?=\))` is a zero-width lookahead assertion which matches
  a trailing right paren without including it in the result.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='[(][^)]+)' -F'[(),]' -v OFS=, '{$0=RT} $3==999{print $3, $4}' file
999,'sometext'
999,'othertext'
```