# how to take mysql dump in debian 9 like database names with command

Tags: mysql

how to take MySQL with similar names in Debian.
for example databases like db_test_1, db_test_2, db_test_3, these databases i want take dump at a time without mentioning them multiple times.

just by mentioning db_test_* it has to give similar names back up.

i need command to take backup please 
thanks in advance

Comment: Check this answer on serverfault, it has been previously answered https://serverfault.com/questions/442889/wildcard-backup-mysql-databases

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876754/split-up-a-mysqldump-file-with-multiple-databases-by-database

Comment: @namelivia can you give sample example please elaborate