# how import a mysqldump file locally

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

I want to import an sqldump file in my database "dbname" into the table "data" without using the network interface.

when i import the file via

```
mysql dbname -u databaseuser -pdatabasepass<data.sql
```

this is **really** slow on my ubuntu 12.04

but when i use this instead:

```
mysqlimport -u databaseuser -pdatabasepass --local data.sql
```

it is as fast as normal.

i think, because on my mashine it is parsing each line separately when using "mysql" and "<"

is there a way to use the mysqlimport syntax for importing an sql-file with CREATE and DROP TABLE stuff?

maybe just split the upper part in the sql-dump (with the drop table and create table statement) automatically and then only send the rest of the file with the INPUT-statements to mysqlinsert, that should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this script: [How do I split the output from mysqldump into smaller files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16840625/1069083)

and modify it, so you have only the create-statements in one file and the data statements in another.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that directly. What you need to do is run `mysqldump --tab` instead of the normal mysqldump, that will create both a .sql files containing table definitions and a CSV file containing data that can be imported with mysqlimport.

Comment: no, mysqlimport works also with the full sql dumpfile, it ignores the create statement and throws some warnings, but if the table already exists and is empty, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can [specify the path to a UNIX socket file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_socket) with `--socket=/path/to/...` (or -S), which may be faster. You can find the socket path in the server's my.cnf. So, for example (and I'm just making up the path, here);

```
mysql dbname -u databaseuser -pdatabasepass -S /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock < data.sql
```