# PHP CLI running out of memory

Tags: php, memory

I'm trying to reserialize a 1gb sql dump using the fix-serialization.php file from https://github.com/Blogestudio/Fix-Serialization/blob/master/fix-serialization.php

with this command:

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 fix-serialization.php dump.sql
```

But I get the following error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 2328100864) (tried to allocate 18446744071742389167 bytes)
```

I get the same error with when I try:

```
php -d memory_limit=2000M fix-serialization.php dump.sql
```

Obviously my computer does not have 18446744071 GB of ram. I'm getting this error on both a MBP and my Ubuntu machine and I've tried running this script on php5.6 and 7

Comment: Can't that file be broken down into different parts?

Comment: Break the file into smaller segments - http://stackoverflow.com/a/28719267/2182349

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you shoud make your own solution. This script won't fit since it reads the whole file at once and then passes the whole file to the *preg_replace*. That regex is quite complex, so it needs a lot of memory for processing such big strings.
You should [read one data line](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php), then [proccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148712/regex-code-to-fix-corrupt-serialized-php-data) that line and write it to the output file. [Open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) input file for reading, and output file for writing, so the data won't get corrupted.

Comment: So when reading the file line by line (in the same script) memory use is decreased? So memory is only allocated while running the regex on a per line basis and does not accumulate for the entire script?

Comment: Yes, when file of any size is opened only small amount of memory is allocated for the handle resource. When you read a line, that data is stored in a variable.

Comment: Ih that's awesome. Ok then, I'll just take that regex and try running it against the dump on a line per line basis.

Comment: Take a note: this very approach can be only taken if each line can be processed by itself, in case if processing needs some wider context, more complex means should be applied.

Comment: This is perfect,  I rewrote the script to run the regex on a line by line basis and it works. thanks!