# Split large text file intelligent

Tags: mysql

I have a large sql file (500mb) and want to split it in chunks. 
I used the shell command split but it doesn't split context-aware before a special pattern (e.g. INSERT) and thus breaks the SQL statement.

The aim is to have two 250mb files both still containing only valid SQL commands. Is this possible?

Comment: If you have a 500MB SQL file you're probably doing something wrong, unless it's a backup. If it's a backup: create the backup in smaller chunks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132902/how-do-i-split-the-output-from-mysqldump-into-smaller-files

Comment: Its for migrate a db to another server. I use phpmyadmin

Comment: Then create the dump with mysqldump in smaller files, see the link.

Comment: mabye that link will help you http://scriptingmysql.wordpress.com/2011/09/14/splitting-a-mysql-dump-file-into-smaller-files-via-perl/

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
mysqldump -u admin -p database1 > /backup/db/database1.sql
```

or

```
mysqldump -u admin -p --all-databases > /backup/db/all_databases.sql
```

If you have only MyISAM tables you can use:

```
mysqlhotcopy -u admin -p password123 database1 /backup
```

for faster backups. *mysqlhotcopy* doesn't generating sql but copying the files of the database.

For recovery of *mysqldumped* databases use:

```
mysql -u admin -p database1 < database.sql
```

or

```
mysql -u admin -p <all_databases.sql
```

For *mysqlhotcopy*:

> To restore the backup from the mysqlhotcopy backup, simply copy the files from the backup directory to the /var/lib/mysql/{db-name} directory. Just to be on the safe-side, make sure to stop the mysql before you restore (copy) the files. After you copy the files to the /var/lib/mysql/{db-name} start the mysql again.

See here: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/07/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqlhotcopy/